# Drop down list not populating from List MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am confused on an issue with the DropDownListFor helper.

I am trying to assign a list of values to the drop down as follows:

Model

```
public Int32 TestID {get;set;}

public List<Int32> ListOfID {get;set;}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeDD {get;set;}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Manage(int id){

    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    model.TimeDD = DropDownManager.TimeDD;

    model.TestID = 12;
    model.ListOfID = new List<Int32>{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    return View(model);
}
```

In the view I have the following:

```
@for(int i = 0; i< ListoFID.Count; i++){

     <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.TestID, Model.TimeDD)</div>
     <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.ListoFID[i], Model.TimeDD)</div>
}
```

The problem I am having is that the TestID drop down is working correctly however the ListoFID[i] is not selecting the values from the drop down.  The TimeDD is a list of times as follows:

```
/// <summary>
        /// The Time dropdown
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userID"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeDD()
        {
            // new ctl
            TimeControl ctl = new TimeControl();

            // get drop down
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> result = ctl.Select().Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Time1, Value = m.TimeID.ToString() }).ToList();

            // clean up
            ctl.Dispose();

            return result;
        }
```

Where Time1 is '09:30' and TimeID is 1 - 48.  I cannot figure out how this is happening!! As soon as I reference an object it fails to select the drop down at the correct point.

**Edit**
Also I have a property in my model called OpeningTimes - this is the list of opening times saved against a company as below:

```
ComapnyID    DayID    StartTime    EndTime
   1           1         19           32        -- e.g. Monday 09:00 - 17:30
```

When I loop through the Opening times:

```
@for(int i=0; i< Model.OpeningTimes.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OpeningTimes[i].StartTime, Model.TimeDD)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OpeningTimes[i].EndTime, Model.TimeDD)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
```

The drop downs are still not being selected.  I can confirm the StartTime and EndTime do have values and are property int

Comment: When you loop through the Opening times.... what?

Comment: My answer still stands. You are trying to map against something that is not a direct property of the Model, which, for `DropDownListFor`, does not work.

Comment: OK is there a workaround to populate a drop down from a list of objects instead of me creating MondayStartTime, MondayEndTime properties in the model?

Answer (score 1):

`DropDownListFor` requires a property to map to, not a value. So

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.ListoFID[i], Model.TimeDD) /* the [i] kills it */
```

will not work.

Comment: Hi please see edit. This is not working when referencing an object and property from my model??

Comment: It is only against a drop down. All other elements like text box etc work correctly

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing a list of int build it like the other

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var temp in Model.ListOfId){
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp, Value = temp});
}
```